# Linq query using list or array of ids

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am having trouble figuring out how to query a db using linq in c# to get all the objects corresponding to a list or array of ids and put them in a list. For example:

I have a table of items. I want to build a method that retrieves all the items whose ids are in a passes array or list. I have googled it but it always assumes i just want to query against a list or array rather than query USING a list or array.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
var query = items.Where(item => validIds.Contains(item.Id));
```

Note that if this is all local (i.e. in-process, LINQ to Objects) and you may have a lot of valid IDs, you probably want to construct a `HashSet<T>`.

Or you could do a join, of course:

```
var query = from id in validIds
            join item in items on id equals item.Id
            select item;
```

(There *are* lots of examples of this on the web and even on Stack Overflow, but I can understand that it's not an easy one to find as all the terms you'd use are common.)

Comment: looks like that would work for my needs. Ill try it out. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this becomes problematic when you have allot of ID's. You will get an error in the lines of `The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters` as contains does not build the query using `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (x,y....z)` but instead injects allot of parameters.

Comment: @ppumkin: Indeed, that ends up being an issue - and to be honest, I don't know what the EF-supported way of coping with that situation is.

Comment: I think I will just build and execute the query manually in this case. Since the ID's are generated from another query it is protected from SQL injections.. I hope. But I cant see any other way to do it either.. unless I use dapper.

Comment: @ppumkin: Depending on what you're doing, you could potentially split the query into multiple queries each of which uses the approach in the answer with a subset of IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Use like that

```
 var subscriptionDetails = SubscriptionMasterBL.GetSubscriptionMasterDetails();
                tempUserList = lstSubscriberUsers.Where(a => subscriptionDetails.Any(b => b.SubscriptionUserId == a.Id 
                    && b.TokenId != Guid.Empty)).ToList();
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work with a local collection of ID's... for some reason. Even though I read somewhere we should use `Any()` as its much faster than `Contains()` .. but didn't realise you could apply it to SQL queries.. any way I get the error `Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.`